# Redirect to another controller after clicking on the button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

### Simple Problem:

I have a button and whenever the user will click on this button, I want to redirect him to another action in another controller. How could I do that?!

This code would be in the `.html.erb` file

```
<%= form.submit "Create Request"%>
```

> Note: i don't want to use link_to! Additionally, I could not use redirect_to in the controller because i used `render` there.

Comment: share the work you have already done, include controller code in question

Answer (score 0):

In your create action within the controller, you can redirect wherever you want after save the  values.
For example:

```
def create
  @model = Model.new(permited_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    If @model.save
      format.html { # todo block with redirect }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **remote: true** in the form , Ex:

```
<% form_tag create_path(params_you_needed), remote: true do |form| %>
```

add rails js for create method create.js.erb

```
$('#id').html('<%= j render(:partial => "file/location", :locals => {data}) %>');
```

and in that you can render the file you need!